# How to use query parameters as controller name in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'd like to make this happen. The URL "index.php?c=controlller&a=action" goes to the "controller@action", controller named "controller" whose action named "action"

According to the document, the close one is by using

```
Route::controller('users', 'UserController');
```

But this one still need to bind the controller manually. I am building an admin site. So I want things to be as simple as possible.

Comment: I'm sure that's possible but... I think it is a really bad idea ! You try to hack the whole http protocol. I suggest you to build a very simple REST application, it is simple and maintenable. Or you can use this standard for your routes : `/actionController`.

Comment: @AlexandreButynski  Thanks, RESTful is a good idea. I also found a way to use "/controller/action" dispatching to controller@action.